# How to print elements from a binary tree ignoring all the repeating ones?

Tags: java, printing, binary-tree

```
 public void printTree(node root)
    {
        if(root != null)
        {
            printTree(root.left);
            System.out.print(root.word + " " + root.line+" ");
            String tempStr=root.word; int tempLn=root.line; //don't know how to use it
            printTree(root.right);
        }
    }
```

Assume that the tree is already sorted in a lexicographic order.

For example, the file is like this:

```
aaa 
zzz
the the the the
```

and the output should be like this:

```
aaa line: 1
the line: 3 3 3 3
zzz line: 2
```

My code now displays the same words for many times. I don't know how to organize this chunk of code.

Comment: would you mind posting your whole tree source code?

Comment: can we modify the methods of your tree? you have to present this result while you walk in the tree or you can accumulate the data in some other structure? You can only use the temps you've cited or can we use a Node temp for example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are instantly outputting information as you find it.  Instead, you need to store the data you come across in a continual fashion.

You will probably want to use a `HashMap<String, List<Integer>>` data structure to hold this information.

Comment: What data structures are you allowed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` to store pairs of `<String, List>`, where `String` will be your key and `List` will be a list of positions, where such key was found. If you need to check, if a key is already in the map, you do

```
map.contains(key);
```

and if there is one, you can update the appropriate list by doing

```
map.get(key).add(page);
```

Comment: is there anything else I can use except for HashMap? I'm sorry to say that I'm not allowed to use it in this assignment...

Comment: you can make your own class for storing both the key and a list of positions and then put these into a simple list