# How to count the occurrence of an element in a tree?

Tags: java, string, printing, count, tree

```
   public int countOccurrences(String target){
       int count=0;
       node cursor=root;
       while(cursor!=null){

              int compare=target.compareTo(cursor.word);
               if(compare==0) {
                      //System.out.println("aa");  stuck in here
                      count++;
                   }
           else if(compare>0) cursor=cursor.right;
           else cursor=cursor.left;
       }

       System.out.println(count);
       return count;
   }
```

I want to find the occurrences of a word in a tree (that is already sorted in a lexicographic order). My code now keeps printing out "aa" all over the screen... help?

Comment: is this question somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841283/how-to-print-elements-from-a-binary-tree-ignoring-all-the-repeating-ones you've posted earlier today?

Comment: @Leo: yes that was me... i'm stuck for a long time >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing cursor at all in your if-statement, you are only changing count, which has no effect on cursor so you get stuck in an infinite loop. You need to change cursor when you find a match as well as incrementing count. See below for an example:

```
if(compare==0) {
    //System.out.println("aa");  stuck in here
    count++;
    cursor = cursor.left 
}
```

This is assuming that the way it is sorted, anything that is equal will be in the left branch. Just change `cursor.left` to `cursor.right` if the opposite is true.